# Sum of a total amount where case is coming in

Tags: mysql

I come across this beautiful link - [How can I return pivot table output in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql)

Which solves my exact problem. However, I need one of the columns as sum of the value - which is an amount column

How to add a sum of a column in the query. Please advise.

Comment: Kindly include the table structure (`create` and `insert` statement) and some data, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT SUM(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition;
```

Comment: sum(case when emp.empstatus!='Y' then emp.amount ELSE 0 END) empTotal